# Apache POI convert pptx to svg , image

Tags: svg, apache-poi, powerpoint

I'm using [Apache POI PPTX to SVG conversion](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/PPTX2SVG.txt). This works for most of it except for images that are embedded into the slides.

These are coming up as blank in the resulting svg files. So a slide such as [image: original slide] comes out as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" stroke-dasharray="none" shape-rendering="auto" font-family="'Dialog'" width="720" text-rendering="auto" fill-opacity="1" contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" color-interpolation="auto" color-rendering="auto" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" font-size="12" fill="black" stroke="black" image-rendering="auto" stroke-miterlimit="10" zoomAndPan="magnify" version="1.0" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="miter" contentStyleType="text/css" font-style="normal" height="540" stroke-width="1" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-weight="normal" stroke-opacity="1">
<!--Generated by the Batik Graphics2D SVG Generator-->
<defs id="genericDefs"/>
<g>
<g fill="white" stroke="white">
<rect x="0" width="720" height="540" y="0" stroke="none"/>
</g>
<g stroke-miterlimit="1" stroke-width="0.25" font-size="44" font-family="'Calibri'" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="round">
<text x="256.875" xml:space="preserve" y="81.5196" stroke="none">Introducing</text>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

**Basically the image is missing.**

How do I fix it? While I would prefer to convert this slide to an svg if possible , would converting it to a png or jpeg fix this issue?
**

### Update

Here are my dependencies

```
"org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.11-beta2",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.11-beta2",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi-scratchpad" % "3.11-beta2",
  "org.apache.xmlgraphics" % "batik-transcoder" % "1.7"
```

Original file is a jpg/jpeg.

---

Also I see this
**Warning: Could not get charToByteConverterClass!**

Comment: What format are your problematic images in? And have you made sure you're using the latest version of Apache POI?

Comment: Added more info to the  question.

Comment: You should never mix and match POI jars from different releases, so I'd suggest you fix that first - get everything onto 3.11 beta 2

Comment: no luck unfortunately, Ive updated all versions. However I do see this warning "Could not get charToByteConverterClass!"

Comment: That error isn't coming from Apache POI, so I wonder if you're missing a dependency needed by Batik?